# Why am I getting "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." in this situation on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, windows-11, start

On Windows 11, I am trying to do this in a `.bat` file:

```
start "nginx" cmd.exe /U /K "C:\nginx\nginx.exe" -c "C:\Users\John Doe\Documents\PHP-dev\Nginx\nginx.conf" -p "C:\nginx"
```

That means: "open a cmd.exe instance with the window title `nginx`, running nginx.exe with the specified arguments, and keep the window alive".

However, it instead opens a **Windows Terminal** instance (with cmd.exe inside) with the text `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` in the top and then it exits the command instantly. Huh?

If I manually run the "actual command", from an already opened cmd.exe or Windows Terminal, the command itself works (doesn't exit or show any error or output):

```
"C:\nginx\nginx.exe" -c "C:\Users\John Doe\Documents\PHP-dev\Nginx\nginx.conf" -p "C:\nginx"
```

I was using the same command on Windows 10 without this issue (and identical directory structures), so obviously, it cannot have to do with anything in the command itself.

If instead I do:

```
start "nginx" "C:\nginx\nginx.exe" -c "C:\Users\John Doe\Documents\PHP-dev\Nginx\nginx.conf" -p "C:\nginx"
```

... then it does run (no error), **but** it does this in a Windows Terminal instance rather than cmd.exe, which breaks the taskbar grouping which I'm after!

What could it possibly be doing due to the `cmd.exe /U /K` (or `cmd.exe /U /C`) part which "invalidates" the command?

I just want it to open as a proper cmd.exe (not wrapped in Windows Terminal), just like all my other such instances which were started in the same way and by the same `.bat` file, and not display any weird error.

Comment: "I just want it to open as a proper cmd.exe (not wrapped in Windows Terminal)" - I don't believe this to be possible, since Microsoft with the release Windows Terminal, formally replaced PowerShell with Windows Terminal.  Prior to this change Microsoft changed the default terminal application from Command Prompt to PowerShell. *If it's still possible you can find the option within the settings to Command Prompt.*   Your issue might or might have to do with Windows Terminal being the default terminal application.  I am not convinced your command is correct.

Comment: What you can do is associate the .bat file with Windows Terminal.  You would then assign a default profile, preferably not Command Prompt, as the default profile. If I were to guess the switch to use Unicode is the problem.

Comment: But I'm running tons of raw cmd.exe ones. It was in the question. So it must be possible...

Comment: You can manually open command prompt.  My comment was that by default, unless you explicitly run Command Prompt, Windows Terminal as the default terminal host application will be launched.  I don't believe you can change that behavior on Windows 10.  Windows 11 is the only version of Windows where Windows Terminal can be the default terminal application.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, do you have any idea what is happening? Looks like this will never be answered or even seen unless you know the issue.

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with Windows Terminal.  I made a suggestion that you might be able to change the default terminal application, and how to do that, but when I wrote those instructions I wasn't in front of a Windows 11 machine.